# filter properties input file

Tags: java, properties, filter

I've an existing application using language specific properties files.

For better handling I want to work within a single file only and
select entries while reading the file. The format should be

```
...
//en myValue=myValue
//ge myValue=meinWert
...
```

instantiated for 'ge' properties loading should only catch

```
...
myValue=meinWert
...
```

I like to stick with the Properties class and hand over an
e.g. FilterInputStream.

Is this the right way to go or any better idea?

thanks
Wolfgang R.

Comment: This is not a properties file. It's okay to come up with your own file format, but a Java properties file has a specific, well-defined meaning, and this isn't it. Typically, for multiple languages, multiple properties files are used.

Comment: You may want to use ResourceBundles, as described in this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270067/how-to-handle-multiple-languages-in-java

Comment: David, the today's version uses .en and .ge properties files read-only.
But it's a good point to re-think how far to go away from the original semantic.
Beside my 5 chars prefix addition I do not have to evaluate the string handling currently defined by the Properties class. Putting it into the InputStream is a runtime pre-processing only and not touching a wider scope.

Comment: This has been a solved problem for well over a decade in Java. Also, the standard two-letter abbreviation for German is 'de' (Deutsch).

Answer (score 0):

```
String langTag = "en"; //Example
try {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<path to file>));
    String inputString;
    while((inputString = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if(inputString.substring(2, 4).equals(langTag))
            //Do something
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

I will admit the while loop is very doubious.

Comment: The `while` loop is the standard idiom in Java for reading files line-by-line. But `substring(0, 2)` is going to give you the `//` from the file format in the question, not the language tag.

Comment: Ah. I thought the `//`s were just for example. I am not sure about the stability of the while loop (exception throwing and such).

Comment: Well, I could be wrong, but I understood the question to indicate they would actually be present in the file.

Comment: Yes, this is the actual file format. 5 characters prefix for each line. Either to ignore the line or use that line but drop these first 5 chars.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask if this is the right way, I answer **NO** unless you have a very good reason to do so. You are about to replace a core JDK fuctionnality that is extensively tested, used and probably correctly optimized by your own ... that **you** will have to test and maintain.

You'd didn't say **why** you want a different format for your properties file. I presume you simply find it easier to maintain. If its the real reason, you'd better contemplate a preprocessor task (in ant, maven or ... a simple batch) that take your proposed format as input and produces standard properties files. That way :

- you have your prefered format in edition
- the app has its standard format in production
- the conversion only occurs when properties are modified

If you look how advanced CSS frameworks (SASS, LESS or Stylus) work, they do have an internal format that is pre-processed to produce standard CSS files.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I find it easier to maintain a single file with the language variations below each other.
Beside this single file I would like to stay within Java only and the used Properties class as well.