# When making a GUI in Java SWING, how can I keep the strings in a separate modular file?

Tags: java, xml, swing, user-interface

My experience in making interfaces comes mostly from Android Studio. Now I am using Swing. In Android Studio it is custom that you keep all your displayed strings in a separate xml file. This is all automatically generated and hooked up behind the scenes.

I would like to do something similar in Java (Swing) to keep everything modular and make future translation or adaptation easier, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: The `ResourceBundle` class was designed for this purpose.

Comment: Java already has a built-in mechanism for translatable strings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270067/how-to-handle-multiple-languages-in-java

Comment: Alright, thank you! Google didn't get me there, but that is indeed what I wanted!